# Access DataSource results in Exception Null UserID passed and Connection cannot be created

Tags: hibernate, jpa, nullpointerexception, datasource, websphere-7

I have been working on this issue from couple of days, without a resolution. I hope posting my question here will direct me in the right direction. I browsed many forums and all stated the same steps that I followed (stated below), Still I get the same run time exception on accessing Datasource.

```
Exception - 
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not open connection
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:122)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientException: [jcc][t4][10205][11234][4.11.88] Null userid is not supported. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815 DSRA0010E: SQL-Status = 42815, Fehlercode = -4'461
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:676)
```

Environment - Hibernate, JPA 2.0, DB2, Websphere 8.0, RAD, Java EE 6 Deploymnet.

1. Created a datasource on Websphere JDBC/Sample. Created a J2C authentication using DB credentials on the DataSource. Assigned the authentication to DataSource via Container Managed authenitcation.
2. Web.xml entries

   ```
   resource-ref
   res-ref-name Sample
   res-type javax.sql.DataSource
   res-auth Container
   res-sharing-scope Shareable
   resource-ref
   ```
3. Ibm-web-bnd.xml entry

   ```
   resource-ref name="jdbc/Sample" binding-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/Sample"
   ```
4. Persistence.xml

   ```
   persistence-unit name="samplePool" transaction-type="JTA"
   provider org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
   jta-data-source jdbc/Sample
   properties
   property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"         value="org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup"
   property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2390Dialect"
   properties
   persistence-unit
   persistence
   ```
5. Code within Dao

   ```
    eMgrFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("samplePool");
    entityMgr = eMgrFactory.createEntityManager();
    entityMgr.createNativeQuery();
   ```

Please note after creating the datasource via Admin Console Iam able to test the connection successfully. Also note if I specify the Component Managed Authentication Iam able to access thru code. Advise how I could access via Container Managed authentication.

Answer (score 0):

After deployment you have to map the datasource to your application.

[Map resource references documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Fudat_maprrr.html).

Comment: I tried resource references section. It did not help.
To me Deployment descriptors should take care of configuration settings.

Further suggestions are always welcome.

Regards,
Kalyan.

Answer (score 0):

Today I am able to find a solution for my question. Whole of the issue turns out to be a configuration one. Good that I am able to resolve.
Following are the changes that I made

1. persistence.xml file - I no more do DataSource direct lookup from here. I lookup(java:comp/env/jdbc/ds) at web.xml like this

```
xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    persistence-unit name="dataPool" transaction-type="JTA"
        provider org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence provider
        jta-data-source java:comp/env/jdbc/ds jta-data-source

        shared-cache-mode ALL shared-cache-mode

        properties
        property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2390Dialect"
        property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="A11"
        property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup"  
        property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform"
        property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"
        properties

    persistence-unit
persistence
```

1. In Web.xml I look up the DataSource

```
 
    resource-ref
        res-ref-name jdbc/ds res-ref-name
        lookup-name ACTUAL DATASOURCE lookup-name
        res-type javax.sql.DataSource res-type
        res-auth Container res-auth
        res-sharing-scope Shareable res-sharing-scope
    resource-ref
```

I post the solution for others.